# Hide paragraph <p> on checked 'Use Billing Address'

Tags: javascript, spree, street-address

In my Spree application, if I check "Use Billing Address" checkbox, the Shipping address gets hidden by the checkout.js. I want to display more text inside but I could not make it toggle hide with the form values.

```
<div class="inner">
 <p id="szip" class="field">
  <%= ship_form.label :zipcode, t(:zip) %>
  <%= ship_form.text_field :zipcode %>
 </p>
 <p>This is where I want to insert the TEXT</p>
</div>
```